# Extract substring from 'list' of strings

Tags: shell, text-processing

I have a file with lines with IDs, and I'm extracting certain substrings from each line. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/428109/1075247) answer, which is great, but I don't know how to get it to execute on each line. I figure `xargs` should be part of this, but I'm not sure.

As an example, I have this:

1234**0001**1234
9737**0002**1234
28399**0003**1235
8279**0004**1234

(Emboldedned for clarity)

And I want to *for each* line above to extract this:

0001
0002
0003
0004

Now I know that if *one* of the lines was `$line_one`, I could use `echo ${line_one: -8:4}` to grab the first 4 characters, of the last 8 characters. But I have the lines coming out of the previous command (which is something like `cut -d "|" f1`, (I think, I'm not at the PC that has the file in question, and that PC doesn't have internet)). What I'm imagining is some world where I can run this:

```
cut -d "|" -f1 | xargs echo ${xargs_line: -8:4}
```

To get my output....

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cut -d "|" -f1 | while read line; do echo ${line: -8:4}; done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the whole thing with just `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{print substr($1,length($1)-7, 4)}' f1
```

#### Example

Sample data file `f1`:

```
$ cat f1
123400011234|blah|blah
973700021234|blah|blah
2839900031235|blah|blah
827900041234|blah|blah
```

Running the command produces this:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{print substr($1,length($1)-7, 4)}' f1
0001
0002
0003
0004
```